# Custom SQL for Reporting on catalogsearch_query Table

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing a query for grouping and concatenating query IDs on Magento's `catalogsearch_query` table.

***Summary: Can I "CONCAT" results of a `GROUP_CONCAT`?***

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT query_text, 
  store_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(query_id ORDER BY query_id) AS queries
FROM catalogsearch_query 
GROUP BY query_text 
HAVING queries like '%,%' 
ORDER BY query_text
```

Its purpose is to identify potentially duplicate entries on the table by returning unique results per `query_text` value across all stores. Here's a sample of my output:

```
*************************** 12597. row ***************************
query_text: blue shirt
  store_id: 5
   queries: 2332223,2332233
*************************** 12598. row ***************************
query_text: blue shirt
  store_id: 11
   queries: 2202093,2202103
*************************** 12599. row ***************************
query_text: hat
  store_id: 5
   queries: 2458333,2458343
*************************** 12600. row ***************************
query_text: hats
  store_id: 5
   queries: 2207433,2207443
```

So you can see that, per record, I have a list of `queries` values. **What I want to do now is concatenate those values into a single resulting value, so that my result set looks like this**:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   queries: 2332223,2332233,2202093,2202103,2458333,245834,2207433,2207443
```

My goal would be to leverage this as part of a `DELETE` operation where these duplicates are removed. But the structure of my query does not allow for that in SQL. I realize that I can write a script to parse the results and build a new query to remove records, but I want to accomplish this purely with SQL as a self-learning point.

(note: I would be adding to the delete query a date range, so that results are based on records which have an `updated_at` value of prior to 2014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I opted to stick with this query and use it to create a temporary table from which I could aggregate and delete duplicates.

**Create Temporary Table**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qt AS (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT query_text, 
    store_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(query_id ORDER BY query_id) AS queries 
  FROM catalogsearch_query 
  GROUP BY query_text, 
  store_id 
  HAVING queries like '%,%' 
  ORDER BY query_text
);
```

**Reading Queries Into An Array**

```
$write      = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$readSql    = "SELECT queries FROM qt";
$results    = $write->fetchAll($readSql);
$ids        = array();

foreach ($results as $row) {
  $rowIds = explode(',', $row['queries']);

  // Preserve 1 record (with highest ID)
  sort($rowIds, SORT_NUMERIC);
  array_pop($rowIds);

  $ids = array_merge($ids, $rowIds);
}
```

Removing Duplicates

```
$deleteSql  = "DELETE FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE query_id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ");";
$results    = $write->query($deleteSql);
```

So it's less than ideal, and slow given the `IN()` on a `WHERE` clause. But for a one-off cleanup script, it gets the job done.